# Auth Dialog Preview User can't see page tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-test-users

I logged in as my app's test user, **Auth Dialog Preview User** to view tabs of a certain page from there. But they're not showing, and the page displays its timeline instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the page or app restricted by age or location?

Comment: is the app still in sandbox mode or something else like that?

Comment: No. Actually I discovered that it can't view tabs from any page. http://www.facebook.com/cocacola <--- even that one. So I guess the test user cannot really be used for testing tabs. :|

Comment: they should be able to, as far as i know :/